# How do I move an element up/down one position in tree

Tags: javascript, nodes

I cannot seem to find what should be a basic function of JavaScript. I want to move an element up one position or down one position by a button click. jQuery and other proprietary libraries are not an option.

```
function moveDown()
{
    if (document.getElementById('CMSeditingNode'))
    {
        var node = document.getElementById('CMSeditingNode'),
        parent = node.parentNode,
        nextNode = node.nextSibling,
        secondNode = nextNode.nextSibling,
        oldChild = parent.removeChild(node);
        parent.insertBefore(oldChild, secondNode);
    }
}
```

The answer worked perfectly and I have add to this post a supplement for insertAfter().

Comment: What have you tried? What have you researched? What went wrong? What mark-up are you using?

Comment: I have searched according to my question here and several variances. I tried using contenteditable > grab by id > create new with outerHTML then removing old div. as you can see by the description this was quite convoluted. what markup? HTML

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The methods/properties you're looking for are [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.parentNode), [previousSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.previousSibling), [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.nextSibling), [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.removeChild), [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore), and [insertAfter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertAfter).  A snippet might look like:

```
var node = document.getElementById('somenode'),
    parent = node.parentNode,
    prev = node.previousSibling,
    oldChild = parent.removeChild(node);
parent.insertBefore( oldChild, prev );
```

Just for comparison, the (complete) jQuery for this would be:

```
var $node = $('#somenode'),
            $node.prev().before($node);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I will begin working with this.